Is SbF3 ionic or covalent?
My textbook says:
Trihalides (of group 15) except BiF3 are predominantly covalent in nature.
But I see a lot of sources say that SbF3 is ionic. I am confused as to whether SbF3 should be taken as predominantly ionic or covalent.

I don't think it's predominantly either.

Which source says it is ionic?

The bonds between antimony and fluorine is covalent. However, since it is a solid, the molecules doesn't float around but is linked together in a crystal lattice. The fancy word for it is called stibium bond.

(Source)
You can find more details below:

Judit Molnár, Mária Kolonits, Magdolna Hargittai, Molecular structure of SbF3 and BiF3: an electron diffraction study, Journal of Molecular Structure, 1997, DOI: 10.1016/S0022-2860(97)00057-4

The Stibium Bond or the Antimony-Centered Pnictogen Bond: The Covalently Bound Antimony Atom in Molecular Entities in Crystal Lattices as a Pnictogen Bond Donor by Arpita Varadwaj, Pradeep R. Varadwaj, Helder M. Marques and Koichi Yamashita, Int J Mol Sci. 2022, DOI: 10.3390/ijms23094674


